# Why my HttpPost doesn't work?

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp, slim

I have a problem. I'm trying to make a `REST API` for `Android` but my `HttpPost` doesn't work. I'm using `XAMPP` and `Slim framework` for this issue.

I have my `POST` method created in which I want to add one new `Car` to the table `cars`.

The constructor of my `Car` object is:

```
public Car(int idCar, String name, Date dateBuyCar)
{
    this.idCar = idCar;
    this.name = name;
    this.dateBuyCar = dateBuyCar;
}
```

My `POST` method with `Slim` it's like:

```
$app->post("/cars/",function() use($app)
{
    $idCar = $app->request->post("idCar");
    $name = $app->request->post("name");
    $dateCar = $app->request->post("dateCar");

    try{
        $connection = getConnection();
        $dbh = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO cars VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $dbh->bindParam(1,$idCar);
        $dbh->bindParam(2,$name);
        $dbh->bindParam(3,$dateCar);

        $dbh->execute();
        $cars = $connection->lastInsertId();
        $connection = null;

        header("HTTP/1.1 200");
        header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($cars,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

And I make my `HttpPost` method like this:

```
class addCarDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private Car newCar;

    addCarDatabase(Car newCar)
    {
        this.newCar = newCar;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String date = null;

        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(newCar.getDate());

        String url = "http://IP of my computer/project/cars/";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

        BasicNameValuePair idCarValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("id", newCar.getIdCar());
        BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCar.getName());
        BasicNameValuePair dateValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("date", newCar.getDateBuyCar());


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairList.add(idCarValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(nameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(dateValuePair);

        try{

            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
            method.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(){
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(){
    }
}
```

And in my `MySQL` database (I use `phpmyadmin` to administrate it) I have three columns, each of them for one of the attributes of the new `Car` that I want to add:

```
--> id(int)
--> name(String)
--> dt(date)
```

I think that the problem it's because I have a `Date` in my object but I'm not secure of that. I think it could be the problem because I saw that the dates in `phpmyadmin` are stored like `2010-12-06` and when I use my application I need the date like `06-12-2010` so inside the application I parse it. I parse it again to enter the date of the new `Car` with the format that it has in `phpmyadmin` (Like you can see in the `AsyncTask`).

I know that all the information comes right to the `AsyncTask` because I checked it with some `Logs` but when it arrives to the `HttpPost` nothing happens.

What could be the problem?

**P.S:** I know that the connection to the database with `XAMPP` it's correct because I make a `GET` method and it works properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you inserted the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> permission into the manifest?

Comment: @SimoV8 Yes, I have it.

Comment: could you post the locgat with the stacktrace?

Comment: @SimoV8 I have an extended logcat (In my question I only foccused on my problem) but I didn't see any error or something like that. What exactly wants about the logcat?

Comment: You should look into using the Volley networking library.

Comment: Your identifiers in `$idCar = $app->request->post("idCar");
    $name = $app->request->post("name");
    $dateCar = $app->request->post("dateCar");` do not match with those in `BasicNameValuePair idCarValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("id", newCar.getIdCar());
        BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCar.getName());
        BasicNameValuePair dateValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("date", newCar.getDateBuyCar());`.

Comment: @zgc7009 I will see it for the next project (Nowadays I don't have too much time to change all my project) and I'm very grateful for your advice but, do you know what could I do for this code works?

Comment: @greenapps What do you mean? That I have to put it like `BasicNameValuePair("idCar", newCar.getIdCar());`, I mean, to put the same name in the `BasicNameValuePair` as in the `$app->request->post`?

Comment: @greenapps I checked it and put them equals in both places and it still doesn't work. Could be the problem with the `Date`?

Comment: You are not reading the response/echo of the php script. So you will not know what is echoed. Start reading the echos and tell us what is echoed.

Comment: You keep telling that it does not work. But you should exactly tell us what happens instead and how you know that. Change your script to do nothing with the database yet. Just echo the values of all parameters to see if they came in correct. If you dont you stay 'blind'.

Comment: @greenapps Ok, now it works (just closing the project and opening it again) but I don't understand what you mean with "You are not reading the response/echo of the php script." And thank you for all your help, it helps me a lot!

Comment: The php script echo()s json text or error message. You do not read them.

Comment: @greenapps And how can I do that?

Comment: If you had looked around a bit on this site you would long have found that. How could you say `Now it works` if your client does not read `echo json_encode($cars,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );`? What does work?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936047/how-to-read-response-of-php-code-to-android-java-code?noredirect=1#comment51783392_31936047

Comment: @greenapps Ahh you mean that. I saw it before in some questions and answers but I though it was a type of debug (I just used it before when I have doubts of what was giving to me, the rest of the time I check it directly on the database) And I know that it works because I saw it manually on my database. Thank you for your advices!

Comment: `I check it directly on the database`. Thta is not directly. I'ts afterwards. You check it directly by reading the echos. So make them informative in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you again for all your advices! They help me a lot ;)

Comment: @Error404, in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071844/why-my-httpdelete-doesnt-work) you say that POST requests are working. Have you found a solution for this question here? If yes, please share that as an answer. You are welcome to answer your own questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @GustavoStraube Yes, I solved it. Sorry for being too much time without answering this question but I completely forgot it. Thank you very much  for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used different `ID's` in the `AsyncTask` and in the `POST` method.

For example, when I tried to retrieve on my `POST` method the information from my `AsyncTask`:

```
$idCar = $app->request->post("idCar");
$name = $app->request->post("name");
$dateCar = $app->request->post("dateCar");
```

I was using the `ID's`: `idCar`, `name` and `dateCar`.

But when I was trying to send the information to the `POST` method on my `AsyncTask`:

```
BasicNameValuePair idCarValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("id", newCar.getIdCar());
BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCar.getName());
BasicNameValuePair dateValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("date", newCar.getDateBuyCar());
```

I was using the `ID's`: `id`, `name` and `date`.

So the `POST` method couldn't retrieve the information from the `AsyncTask` because the `ID's` that I was using there were different respect the `POST` method.

To solve this problem I had to change the `ID's` from the information that I was sending on my `AsyncTask`. The code will look like:

```
BasicNameValuePair idCarValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("idCar", newCar.getIdCar());
BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCar.getName());
BasicNameValuePair dateValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("dateCar", newCar.getDateBuyCar());
```